# To show the Opportunity table sorted by Amount field in ascending order in lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, wrapper-class

I am working on the requirement in Salesforce Lightning in which I have to display the table for Opportunity object with row sorted by amount field in ascending order.

Apex class:

```
Public class OpportunityListController {
 @AuraEnabled
 Public static List<opportunityWrapper> getOpportunityList () {
List<opportunityWrapper> opportunityWrapList = new List<opportunityWrapper>();
For (opportunity opp: [select name,stageName,amount from opportunity]){

opportunityWrapList.add (new 
     OpportunityWrapper(opp.name,opp.stageName,opp.amount));

  }

  If(opportunityWrapList!= null && opportunityWrapList.size () > 0) {

     opportunityWrapList.sort ();

     }

  Return opportunityWrapList;

   }

 Public class OpportunityWrapper implements comparable {
  @AuraEnabled
   Public String oppName {get;set;}
  @AuraEnabled
  Public String oppStageName {get;set;}
  @AuraEnabled
  Public Decimal oppAmount {get;set;}


    Public opportunityWrapper (String oppName,String oppStageName,decimal 
  oppAmount){

     This.oppName = oppName;
     This.oppStageName = oppStageName;
     This.oppAmount =oppAmount;



    }

    Public Integer compareTo (Object compareTo) {

      opportunityWrapper oppW = (opportunityWrapper)compareTo;

      Integer returnValue = 0;

       If (oppAmount > oppW.oppAmount) {

       returnValue = 1;

        } else if (oppAmount < oppW.oppAmount) {

            returnValue = -1;

         }

        Return returnValue; 

       }

         }

       }
```

Lightning component:

```
<aura:component controller="OpportunityListController" 
    implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
  <aura:attribute name="ListOfOpp" 
   type="OpportunityListController.OpportunityWrapper[]" />
  <aura:attribute name="selectedCount" type="integer" default="0"/>
  <aura:attribute name="opp" type="Opportunity" />

     <!--aura init handler , call js "loadContactList" function on component 
 load, and display contact data on table-->   
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action=" 
       {!c.loadOpportunityList}"/>


<!--contacts table part--> 
  <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">

        <th>
           <span class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</span>      
        </th>
        <th>
           <span class="slds-truncate" title="Stage">Stage</span>
        </th>
        <th>       
           <span class="slds-truncate" title="Amount">Amount</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!--table body start, 
     Iterate contact list as a <tr>
     -->
  <tbody>
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.ListOfOpp}" var="opp">
        <tr>

           <td scope="row">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!opp.Name}"><a>{!opp.Name}</a></div>
           </td>
           <td scope="row">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!opp.stageName}">{!opp.stageName}</div>
           </td>
           <td scope="row">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!opp.amount }">{!opp.amount}</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </aura:iteration>
  </tbody>
   </table>
   </aura:component>
```

Controller js:

```
({
loadOpportunityList : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('gdfgd');
     var action = component.get('c.getOpportunityList');
     action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
         //store state of response
         var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
           //set response value in ListOfContact attribute on component.
           component.set('v.ListOfOpp', response.getReturnValue());

         }
        });
               $A.enqueueAction(action);
         }
       })
```

Ouput:
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: i'm going to assume this post has been downovetd du to lack of details, such as 'what have you tried to correct this issue' ? any debugging info? As is, you are basically asking for a code review.

Comment: Since I am new to Salesforce Lightning, I dont know why I am not able to see the output. I have tried to put debug statement[console.log('gdfgd');] but nothing has been captured. Can you please help me on this

Comment: please make sure you **[edit]** your post with a precise description of your problem alongside any debug info. Stating that you are new to lightning will not help draw attention, and if this is truly the case, you might want to review the [trailehad modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics) on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I copied you code exactly and got no errors and was able to see the console.log message.

The only issue I see in your code is that you are not referencing the correct attributes of your wrapper class in your table. You have to keep in mind you're not looping over the opp, you're looping over a class that contains fields derived from your opp:

```
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ListOfOpp}" var="oppWrapper">
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!oppWrapper.oppName}"><a>{!oppWrapper.oppName}</a></div>
                </td>
                <td scope="row">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!oppWrapper.oppStageName}">{!oppWrapper.oppStageName}</div>
                </td>
                <td scope="row">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!oppWrapper.oppAmount }">{!oppWrapper.oppAmount}</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
```

After making that change your component works perfectly for me. My only concern is that there is no WHERE or ORDER BY on the query which tells me you may be trying to truncate your code for troubleshooting purposes (which is good) but could be the reason I don't see any errors.

If you get "internal server errors" it's always a good idea to check the developer console for apex errors. If you're getting an internal server error, please paste the error from the dev console so we can help troubleshoot.